# How can I pass a collection to a Modal in MVC with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

So I have a table that will show rows per item in my Model, no big deal.

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              <tr>
                <td>@(String.Format("{0} {1}", item.FirstName, item.LastName))</td>
                <td>@item.Gender </td>
                <td>@item.Age </td>
```

...

However, I also have collections in my model, one of which is Education. So in essence a profile can show all of their eduction, High School, College,etc. I chose to show this in it's own Modal with a button in the row to expand the education list.

```
 <td> @if (item.Education != null){
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eduModal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
                        </button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span>No Education Listed</span>
                    }
                </td>
```

So my question is, how can I pass just the current item.education collection to the modal? If that count is 2 only 2 records should show up. I know there's something I'm missing I just can't figure out what.

As you'd expect my current solutions so All Education across all users not the selected one

```
 <!-- Education Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="eduModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eduModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="eduModalLabel">Education</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>School</th>
                            <th>School Type</th>
                            <th>Start Year</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            if (item.Education != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var e in item.Education)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@e.School</td>
                                        <td>@e.schoolType </td>
                                        <td>@e.startYear </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery to call your action method. Have the action method return the view bound to the updated model (with your updated collection. Then on the success function of your AJAX call just replace the contents of the modal.

You can also make the contents of the modal a partial class and have your controller just return the partial class and have jquery update the contents.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea... then I could make the model of the partial the education type and pass that. I'll try it out and mark correct if it works.

Comment: @Ucf_Falcon - Yep, I have used it in the past and it has worked rather well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) show you exactly how to do this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You literally put that in your for loop so it repeats that code for each item, filling in the modal body with whatever you want to show for the current item's education information.

The only thing you need to fiddle with is the `data-target` of the button and the `id` of the modal. You'll need to assign something unique for each iteration. For example you can just use something like `data-target="#EducationModal@(item.Id)"` and `id="EducationModal@(item.Id)"`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bad idea since then I'd have X number of modal's in my code? I mean I could have like 200 profiles and then have 200 modals built, wouldn't that be a serious resource drain?

Comment: No, its just HTML, and thats cheap. The JS is only activated by clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks, Because I ended up rendering a partial control I technically implemented your solution as well, Just more MVC in nature. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. That's fine. I didn't mean you literally had to put thay HTML in your for loop. However, since you mentioned something about 200 items, be advised that partials are not free. Each partial you call is a separate view that must be loaded and parsed by Razor. A few here and there is fine, but if you're talking hundreds it could have a significant performance impact. If you want to balance performance with modularity, it might be best to have the for loop itself be the partial with the HTML directly inside. Then you just have one partial to render.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i make an ajax call in the event click of the button, call an ActionResult that recieves the selected id and returns a partial with the education information. Then with jquery put the result in  the Modal.